# Hyperledger Fabric: can't find config for root certificate

Tags: ssl, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, x509certificate

I'm trying to build a Hyperledger Fabric network for **version 1.4.6**. I thought I had finally gotten most of it going. I tried, from the `cli` image:

```
peer channel create -o orderer.diro.umontreal.ca:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/indepedent/orderer/msp/tlscacerts/tls-cert.pem
```

But the logs for the orderer always said that the TLS connection failed. So then I tried to change `--cafile` to `--certfile`. The file in question is a certificate, after all. And I got this:

```
peer channel create -o orderer.diro.umontreal.ca:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --certfile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/indepedent/orderer/msp/tlscacerts/tls-cert.pem
Error: failed to create deliver client: failed to load config for OrdererClient: unable to load orderer.tls.rootcert.file: open : no such file or directory
```

I have no idea where this `orderer.tls.rootcert.file` setting comes from. I looked at everywhere I could think of that sets a TLS root certificate for the orderer, including the `fabric-ca-server-config.yaml` settings file, but I still get that message Apparerntly, I need to set it somewhere extra. I just don't know where. It's set in the `base/peer-base.yaml` file and I made sure that it now points to current values.

I'm completely out of ideas of where I can set a value that will even change this message. It's not even about giving it the right value; it's just about finding out where to set it.

Answer (score 0):

The orderer container is not able to find the TLS root certificate. Check the path inside docker container corresponding to `/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls`. I think this folder is empty or atleast cannot find the `ca.crt` inside it.

If you are using different mount paths, check in the `docker-compose` file for the orderer container that where you are mounting the following folder inside the it.

`crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/`

Comment: I checked the path, and it does contain `ca.crt`. But I made `ca.crt` myself and maybe I did it wrong. This is how I did it: `openssl x509 -outform DER -in ca-cert.pem -out ca.crt`. So that's what's at `ca.crt`. Is that wrong? I have access to the private key if that's needed. `fabric-ca-server init` did not make `crt` files.

Comment: I tried making another `crt` file with the private key as part of the input with the `-signkey` option, but I got the same result as before.

Comment: .crt is not different from .PEM file. `ca.crt` is organization's root TLS certificate. Which could be kept same as `ca-cert.pem`. So you directly copy that file to required folders as `ca.crt` without changing any sort of formatting.

Comment: I tried that and I still have a TLS error from the orderer log's point of view when I use the `--cafile` option. `ca.crt` is specified in the YAML startup script as `ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]` I used bash to go into the container and made sure that path is correct.

Comment: Actually, now that I come and think of it, `[...]/orderer/msp/cacerts/localhost-7054.pem` and `ca-cert.pem` are identical. I mean, if you do an md5sum of both, you get the same thing. I may not be an expert, but I don't think it's possible that a certificate wants itself as a client. That would defeat the purpose. Or am I wrong and are they really supposed to be the same file under a different name, as in shared outside the public network during setup? I know that with elliptic curve cryptography, a shared secret can be established by public keys only. But they must be different public keys.

Comment: And similarly `[...]/orderer/msp/tlscacerts/tls-cert.pem` has the same content as the root TLS certificate file for the orderer. Is that wrong? The content of `cacerts` was made automatically be the `fabric-ca-client` program.

Comment: Okay so for your scenario, you must copy `[...]/orderer/msp/tlscacerts/tls-cert.pem` as the `ca.crt` file. I just meant that many times, for dev env people use same root certificate as well TLS root certificate.

Answer (score 0):

The correct argument is `--cafile` (`--certfile` is for your client's certificate when using client authentication). But `/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/indepedent/orderer/msp/tlscacerts/tls-cert.pem` seems not to exist (according to your second error). Check that path inside your client (with `ls`, for instance). Maybe the CA certificate has not been included, maybe the file path is not correct (I don't know, "independent" instead of "indepedent"?), maybe the file name...

After checking and fixing that all, if still failing, check your orderer logs.

Comment: An `ls` from inside the `cli` container showed that indeed the specified file exists. I usually rely on tab-completion anyway. For the first command,  For the logs, for the first command, the orderer says, `TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate`. For the second command, nothing at all shows in the orderer's logs. I made these paths myself. The typo is my own. I'm trying to figure out how this thing works and the automatic setup scripts like made it too opaque.